# Alternatives for all google play games deprecated API's?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-games

I want to add multiplayer to my game, using the google play game services API.

Following this post:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html

There are lots of deprecated API:

**Games.Players.getPlayerSearchIntent()

Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers()

Games.Players.loadInvitablePlayers()

The value LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_SOCIAL

Invitations.loadInvitations()

RealtimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent()

TurnBasedMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent()

All methods in the Requests package.**

I didn't find any helpful discussion regarding alternatives for all the deprecated API.

I really don't want to integrate the deprecated API in my game.

May anyone shed some light regarding this?

Thanks in Advance!